# Storage calculation based on a date range and monthly intake using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-range

I have a table `ClientProfile` with below columns

- `StartDate` `date`
- `Units` `Numeric(18,0)`
- `MonthlyIntake` `Numeric(18,0)`
- `ContractMonths` `Numeric(18,0)`

A user is required to select a date range and the query should be able to fetch the number of units stored in the storage room within that date range.

For example:
`StartDate` of the project is `2019-03-01` (`1st March`), The number of total `Units` are `15000`, `MonthlyIntake` of units is `5000` and the `ContractMonths` to store them in the storage area is `6 months`. So when a user selects date range from `01-2019` to `12-2019`, I should be able to get a result like this:

```
Month      Capacity
-------------------
01-2019    0
02-2019    0
03-2019    5000
04-2019    10000
05-2019    15000
06-2019    15000
07-2019    15000
08-2019    15000
09-2019    0
10-2019    0
11-2019    0
12-2019    0
```

I would really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

Comment: Can we see the data in ClientProfile that gave the output you showed ady? I dont get the logic that makes you say that total units is 15000 for 2019-03-01

Comment: @zip, Total units for 2019-03-01 are 5000, not 15000 and it comes from the `MonthlyIntake` column. The monthly intake will keep on adding in the units until the total units are reached which in this case is 15000. Once this quantity is reached it is going to be same till the end of contract.

Comment: @Ady . . . Please show the data types of the columns.

Comment: @Gordon . . . In the output the `Month` column can be a `string` or `varchar` and the `Capacity` column as `numeric`. And the fields in the question already have their data types mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive subquery to expand the data:

```
with cte as (
      select startdate as mon, units, monthlyintake, contractmonths
      from clientprofile
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, startdate) as mon, units + monthyintake, monthlyintake, contractmonths - 1
      from cte
      where contractmonths > 0
     )
select * 
from cte;
```

This gives you the non-zero values for each month.  You can join to a calendar table to get the zero values.

Comment: hi Gordon, the above query does not provide on how to add the `5000` monthly intake of units to get `5000 in march`, (`5000 from march + 5000 in april`) equals `10000 in april` and then (`5000 from march, 5000 from april and 5000 in may`) equal `15000 in may` and then the next 3 months to `remain at 15000`

Comment: @ady . . . There should be a `+` in the CTE.  I fixed the typo.

Comment: I have tried the below code but keep on having the error `Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "units" of recursive query "cte"`. The code is below

Comment: `with cte(startdate ,units,monthlyintake,contractmonths) as (
      select cp.startdate as mon, cp.units, cp.MonthlyBoxIntake, cp.contractmonths
      from clientprofile as cp
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, startdate ) as mon, cast(units as numeric(18,0)) + cast(monthlyintake as numeric(18,0)),cast(monthlyintake as numeric(18,0)) as MonthlyBoxIntake, cast(contractmonths as numeric(18,0)) -1
      from cte
      where contractmonths > 0
     )
select * 
from cte;`

Comment: @ady . . . Do the casts in both parts of the CTE.